# Pycharm: What's the easiest way to go to specific classes in a large program without scrolling? (Something similar to "Outline" in Eclipse)

Tags: python, oop, debugging, pycharm

I have a large program with many different classes which I know the name of when I need. In Eclipse, there's something called "Outline" which has all these classes so I can easily hop between them. What's the easiest way to do this with PyCharm? Is it double click shift? Or is there another way to see an outline?

Comment: Have you tried the "Structure" window? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html

Comment: @NickODell Thanks that's helpful! And what I'm looking for! Do you know if there's a quicker way to search with double tap "Shift" than manually having to click "Classes" there in the search dialog each time?